# Exclude admin from WP_Query Contributors

Tags: wp-query, functions

We are using this code to get a list of all contributors but we would like to exclude the admin from this list. Currently the admin and any role above the contributor role is being shown with this code.

```
$args  = array('exclude' => array( 10, 18, 4, 15, 9 ), 'who' => 'contributors' );$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Comment: We are just looking to get all contributors ONLY and exclude certain contributors from this list. I have tried to follow the documentation but couldn't figure this out. Also there doesn't seem to be a specific answer anywhere for this type of example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize now that you're not talking about WP_Query but *WP_User_Query*. Looking at the documentation for [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) it says this about the `who` parameter:

- **who** *(string)* - Which users to query. **Currently only 'authors' is supported. Default is all users.**

Instead you can use the role parameter and exclude certain users by ID like so:

```
// Grab all contributors
$contributor_ids = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'role'      => 'contributor',
    'exclude'   => array( 10, 18, 4, 15, 9 )
) );
```

You can also pass multiple roles to the above. For more info check out the [section on roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#User_Role_Parameter).